# BIM 360 resend invitation

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

is there a way to check if invited members accepted invitation, and resend invitation if they didn't accept yet or simply deleted their invitation email?

1. at account level
2. at project level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At account level, you can try https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/users-GET/ to check the status of the user. New user of account should be "not_invited" status, and if this user is invited into a project, the status will be "pending" before accepting the invitation.

At project level, try https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/admin-v1-projects-projectId-users-GET/ to check the status of project users.

But, there seems no API available to resend the invitation.